# Extending generic class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have three Java classes. The first two classes extend `ClassA`, and the last one extends `ClassB`.

```
Class1  extends ClassA

Class2  extends ClassA

Class3  extends ClassB
```

I have some duplicated methods in the three classes (Class1-3). In order to avoid having them duplicated I added a `ClassCommon` like so:

```
Class1  extends ( ClassCommon extends ClassA )

Class2  extends ( ClassCommon extends ClassA )

Class3  extends ClassB
```

So my duplicated methods are now in `ClassCommon`, but i still have duplicated method between `Class3` and `ClassCommon`.

I hope I make sens so far.

**My question is:** is there anyway, using generic types, to have this kind of configuration:

```
Class1  extends ClassCommon<ClassA>

Class2  extends ClassCommon<ClassA>

Class3  extends ClassCommon<ClassB>

ClassCommon<E> extends E
```

Comment: is there anyway to avoid duplication in my example ?

Comment: What is the generic type parameter "E" supposed to represent?  Any type?  One of your classes?

Comment: @rgettman either ClassA or ClassB

Comment: It really doesn't seem like this has anything to do with generics; I don't think you quite understand what they are used for, at least not from what you're posting (?)

Comment: @BrianRoach maybe I don't..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about

```
Class1 extends ClassA
Class2 extends ClassA
Class3 extends ClassB
ClassA extends ClassCommon
ClassB extends ClassCommon
```

or, with interfaces:

```
Class1 extends ClassCommon implements ClassA
Class2 extends ClassCommon implements ClassA
Class3 extends ClassCommon implements ClassB
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Use `ClassCommon` as the root of your hierarchy.

```
public abstract class ClassCommon {

    /*
     * Your methods here.
     */
}
```

Then ...

```
public class ClassA extends ClassCommon
public class ClassB extends ClassCommon
```

... and ...

```
public class Class1 extends ClassA
public class Class2 extends ClassA
public class Class3 extends ClassB
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what common functionality you have, but try `ClassCommon` as the root of your class hierarchy:

```
class ClassCommon<E extends ClassCommon<E>>

class ClassA extends ClassCommon<ClassA>

class ClassB extends ClassCommon<ClassB>

class Class1 extends ClassA

class Class2 extends ClassA

class Class3 extends ClassB
```